# Auto increment version number in project.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Base on [Stafford Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469777/stafford-williams) answer in [How can I auto-increment an ASP.NET Core MVC version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33771502/2009915)

To display the version he us :

`@inject Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IApplicationEnvironment appEnv
My version number is @(appEnv.ApplicationVersion)`

but in RTM theres no

`Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IApplicationEnvironment`

how to do this in RTM ? How to Display the project version in view ?

Comment: are you asking "how to display the project version in a view"?

Comment: Read the ASP.NET Core announcements! https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/171

Comment: @tmg yes, how to display it ?

Comment: @tmg thanks for the clue, found it in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784738/auto-increment-version-number-in-project-json)