# project.json "version" autoincrement

Tags: asp.net-core, versioning, project.json

I need to automatically update product version of the dll into which my app is compiled every time. In `project.json`:

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",
```

It doesn't work and if fact I doubt whether I'm doing right.
Also I tried to use Automatic Versions extension for Visual Studio but it didn't cope too.
There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771501/how-can-i-auto-increment-an-mvc-6-version-number) involving Gulp. Maybe there are some ways to solve the problem using only .Net Core tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I auto-increment an MVC 6 version number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771501/how-can-i-auto-increment-an-mvc-6-version-number)

Comment: I'm using .Net Core 1.0.1. I suppose, there is no DNX anymore

Comment: accepted answer is stile valid, as suggests using gulp-bump, that is a nodejs tool, and doesn't relate to DNX

Comment: Ok, I've changed my question

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have found so far is to use `1.*`. Unfortunately [NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver)'s semantic versioning and VS [Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#version)'s is different. VS Code seems more limited in that it doesn't allow leading characters to be anything other than a digit or a space. It doesn't document the fact, both directly and in its link to [SemVer](http://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html), it can use '*' in a limited way either, but I have been able to use it as described here.