# Automatically increment version number in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing a REST API using ASP.NET Core and want the version number to be automatically incremented. This used to be easily by the following pattern in the AssemblyInfo file: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.6.*")].

I have read a couple of suggestions to use gulp or other third party tools to accomplish this, like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771501/how-can-i-auto-increment-an-mvc-6-version-number)

But do I really need a third party tool to get automatically increased version number? Is there no longer a built-in feature to support this? It feels like I'm missing something here.

Comment: Did you see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3174)

Comment: No, I did not - but now I have :-) I may be stupid, but I don't really understand if it should be possible to automatically increase my version number without using any third party tools or scripts.

Comment: Maybe it will return in a later release

Comment: So you mean that it may be possible to automatically increase version numbers in a later release?

Comment: Who can say? they might, they might not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Versioning in Visual Studio 2017 (.NET Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019832/auto-versioning-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core)

Answer (score 5):

if you call `dotnet build /p:Version=YourVersionNumberHere`, the build will also set the assembly version. So in your build scripts you can easily read the current build number and set it as the patch.

For example in appveyor the build number is exposed as a variable called `APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER`, so if you were to use powershell you could call `dotnet build /p:Version=1.0.$env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER`

I do something similar with [appveyor here](https://github.com/TerribleDev/HardHat/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L10), where I set the version number of my nuget package to be the github tag name, and I set the tag name to be a version. So when I want to do a release I just make a github tag of 1.1.0 for example, and it gets published to nuget.